# Apache2 Address already in use ... could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 (can't start apache)

Tags: networking, server, apache2

Tried some things from other answers to this same question. Still can't resolve. One thing to note: I have gitlab-ctl running.

Useful info:

```
balter@bcore:~$ grep -ri listen /etc/apache2
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:Listen 80
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:    Listen 443
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:    Listen 443
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:# Include list of ports to listen on
/etc/apache2/sites-available/bac/gitlab-omnibus-apache24.conf.bac:# Note this config assumes unicorn is listening on default port 8080 and
/etc/apache2/sites-available/bac/gitlab-omnibus-apache24.conf.bac:# gitlab-workhorse is listening on port 8181. To allow gitlab-workhorse to
/etc/apache2/sites-available/bac/gitlab-omnibus-apache24.conf.bac:# listen on port 8181, edit /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb and change the following:
/etc/apache2/sites-available/bac/gitlab-omnibus-apache24.conf.bac:# gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "tcp"
/etc/apache2/sites-available/bac/gitlab-omnibus-apache24.conf.bac:# gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "127.0.0.1:8181"
/etc/apache2/sites-available/gitlab.conf.bac:# Note this config assumes unicorn is listening on default port 8080 and
/etc/apache2/sites-available/gitlab.conf.bac:# gitlab-workhorse is listening on port 8181. To allow gitlab-workhorse to
/etc/apache2/sites-available/gitlab.conf.bac:# listen on port 8181, edit /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb and change the following:
/etc/apache2/sites-available/gitlab.conf.bac:# gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "tcp"
/etc/apache2/sites-available/gitlab.conf.bac:# gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "127.0.0.1:8181"
/etc/apache2/sites-available/gitlab.conf.bac:#Listen 80

balter@bcore:~$ netstat -ntlp | grep 80
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      - 

balter@bcore:/etc/apache2$ cat ports.conf 
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
balter@bcore:/etc/apache2$
```

Answer (score 0):

if you run 'netstat' as superuser:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 80
```

That should show you the process that is using port 80 which might help you along.
Without further info it does sound like maybe Gitlab is already using port 80, on my Gitlab installation it uses nginx on port 80 by default.

Did you maybe do a re-install of Gitlab at some point? Looking at the 'gitlab.conf.bac' file in your grep output and I would guess that you installed Gitlab using Apache first and then maybe did a reinstall using nginx?

So check netstat as sudo and I think that'll be your answer.